# Alternate approach to show a group of order 105 has normal Sylow 5 and 7 subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, alternative-proof, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

This has been asked many times, and in multiple variations, but here is one link for reference:

[Group of Order 105 Having Normal Sylow 5/7 Subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534557/group-of-order-105-having-normal-sylow-5-7-subgroups)

In my attempt, everything is identical up till the point where we show one of the two desired subgroups is normal. From here, my approach differs.

Suppose $n_5 = 1$. Let $H$ be the Sylow $5$-subgroup. Suppose by contradiction that $n_7 = 15$. Let $K_1, K_2, \dots, K_{15}$ be the Sylow $7$-subgroups. Since $H$ is normal, $HK_{i}$ is a subgroup for each $i$. Since the intersection of Sylow $p$-subgroups is trivial, we would have $15$ subgroups of order $5 \cdot 7 = 35$. Clearly this will exceed the value of $105$ giving us a contradiction. This seems to be following the theorem for product of subgroups with one of them normal being a subgroup.

This seems too good to be true, so I tried to think of what could be wrong. The only thing I could think of is that perhaps there is only one subgroup of order $35$. Since all of the Sylow $7$-subgroups are conjugate, perhaps the multiplication yields the same subgroup? I don't believe this is stated in the theorem I'm using, but I could possibly see this happening. After all, it just says that HK is a subgroup, not necessarily a unique subgroup. I would have to put some thought into this, but I could see this happening. Even if this is true though, we would have
\begin{align} 
(3-1) \cdot n_3 &{}+ (5-1) \cdot n_5 + (7 - 1) \cdot n_7 + |HK| \\
&= 1 + 2 \cdot 1 + 4 \cdot 1 + 6 \cdot 15 + 35 \\
&= 132 > \lvert G \rvert
\end{align}

This seems like a much easier way to come to the conclusion. Almost too easy.

Note that $n_3 = 1$ or $7$ and clearly the case of $7$ would make the above even larger. The same approach can be used if $n_5 = 21$ and $n_7 = 1$.

Is this approach flawed? And if so, what is the reason it is flawed?

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: @Shaun this is not a direct product. It is just group multiplication. I will not be using that. See Gallian theorem 7.2 for reference

Comment: No, I mean, for multiplication of numbers (instead of $*$).

Comment: @Shaun personally, I find that more confusing. I prefer saving that notation for direct product. Since this is my question, I would rather leave it as is. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to argue that the  various  $HK_i$ have trivial intersection, but this need not be true. Compare with the situation in $S_3$ with $H$ the unique 3-Slow and the $K_i$ the three 2-Sylows.

Comment: So, let's say the intersection is equal to the entire group. I suppose this would be the worst-case scenario where all of the HK_{i} are equal. Even in this case though, observe the second argument in my question. The number of elements added together even with a single HK would still exceed the order of the group. I gave the numbers in my second part of the question. Is this the case, or am I still missing something?

Comment: Following up on this